# Setting a class instance variable of an extended class

Tags: ruby

How can `Foo` return the value of `@baz`. At the moment `@baz` returns `nil`.

```
module Bar
  @baz = 'baz'

  def get_baz
    @baz
  end
end

class Foo
  extend Bar
end

Foo.get_baz # Currently returns nil
```

If this is not possible, is there a better way to implement this logic?

Comment: Your code should not even return `nil` as you wrote because you are extending `Bar` before you define it. It returns an error.

Comment: Please provide feedback before down voting, which can be used to improve the nature of the question

Comment: @sawa, the result returns `nil`, not an error

Comment: +1 Two downvotes? Bizarre.  Christian, I suggest you edit your question to move the class below the module (a mistake @sawa flagged).  Also, by doing an edit you permit a downvoter to change their vote.  Among other things, downvotes are cast accidentally from time-to-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
module Bar
  attr_accessor :baz
  def get_baz
    @baz
  end
end

class Foo
  extend Bar
end

Foo.baz = 'baz'
Foo.get_baz # => 'baz'
Foo.baz # => 'baz'
```

If we look at `Foo`'s class methods, sure enough:

```
Foo.singleton_methods # => [:get_baz, :baz, :baz=]
```

Let's wander a bit (with `module Bar` unchanged):

```
class Foo
  extend Bar
  include Bar
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.methods.sort # => [:!,..., :baz, :baz=,..., :get_baz,...]
Foo.baz = 'baz'
foo.baz = 'cat'
Foo.baz         # => "baz" 
Foo.baz = 'dog'
foo.baz         # => "cat" 
goo = Foo.new
goo.baz = 'squid'
goo.baz         # => 'squid'
```

We could instead use `extend` to bring in `Bar`'s methods for just a particular instance of `Foo`:

```
class Foo
  extend Bar
end
foo = Foo.new
foo.extend Bar
goo = Foo.new
```

We get the same results as above with `Foo` and `foo`, but

```
goo.baz = 'rhino' # => # NoMethodError: undefined method 'baz='
```

Can't keep `extend` and `include` straight? Maybe this will help: here `extend Bar` within the class definition is equivalent to `Foo.singleton_class.send(:include, Bar)`.